# Replicação unilateral no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, sincronização, replicação

Tenho dois servidores. Um é única e exclusivamente para testes. O outro é para a produção propriamente dita. Eu preciso que o banco de dados de testes, contenha os mesmos dados do banco de dados da produção. Eu não posso fazer um espelhamento, visto que se eu fizer isso, as mudanças no servidor de testes obviamente afetarão os dados da produção, e isso seria catastrófico!

Eu preciso então de uma forma de somente fazer uma sincronização Servidor -> Cliente, sem jamais fazer o inverso (Cliente -> Servidor). Preciso que essa sincronização aconteça todas as noites.

O que pode ser feito neste caso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se é apenas um servidor de testes eu recomendo fortemente fazer a cópia dos dados por demanda e não fazer on-line. Você terá que montar *scripts* que façam isto para você. Em geral é coisa simples, é fazer o *dump* do banco de dados como se fosse fazer um *backup*, colocar no local adequado e restaurar no outro servidor. Provavelmente você não precisa mais que isto. Existem várias formas de obter o mesmo resultado.

Mas se tiver um real motivo para replicar tem algumas formas.

Na verdade a maioria das soluções podem, mesmo que opcionalmente, replicar em apenas uma direção. Eu diria que a maioria só pode fazer em uma direção.

Me parece que você precisa no máximo de uma replicação por *log*. Acho que é o mais simples. A [documentação do PostgreSQL fala sobre isto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html). Tem a opção de *streaming* mas no seu caso é exagero.

O *log shipping* tem baixo *overhead* no servidor principal e funciona bem sem muita complicação. Ela não oferece capacidades de alta disponibilidade ou redundância imediata, nem pode ser usando em balanço de caraga mas não parece ser o que você precisa.

Também tem o [Slony](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slony). Eu acho que é um canhão para matar passarinho mas é uma opção.

Outra opção semelhante é o [Bucardo](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bucardo).

Existem outra soluções que não lhe atende (apesar de eu achar que estas também não são boas ideias) ou eu não conheço. Um deles seria o [PGPool-II](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpool-II) que libera o servidor principal apenas para atender as requisições de produção mas exige um hardware adicional para coordenar o envio de *queries* para os servidores, não é vantagem no seu caso.

O PostgreSQL evoluiu muito e já possui soluções nativas para replicação, dê uma olhada no estado atual antes de considerar as opções apresentadas aqui.

Acho que outras soluções podem ser usadas independente do banco de dados. É possível usar utilitários rodando pelo sistema operacional que repliquem o conteúdo. Mas também duvido que sejam melhores.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: mas o que seria cópia sob demanda?

Comment: Quando você precisa dos dados no servidor de teste, você manda fazer uma transferência dos dados. Precisa fazer um *script* para cuidar disto. Se é teste você não precisa estar coim os dados exatos do servidor de produção em cada segundo.